# Swap contract v Lightning network contract

Tags: gas, uniswap, mainnet

I'm trying to understand the difference between why a swap on, say, Uniswap or some liquidity pool needs gas and must wait to be "included in the next block" and to be confirmed in a few more blocks, whereas on Btc the Lightning Network facilitates instant transaction "off chain" / somehow it mutates the state of the address itself but doesn't require updating the main chain?

Why can't Balancer and Uniswap etc do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why decentralized exchanges like Uniswap and Balancer require gas fees and confirmation time is because they are built on top of the Ethereum blockchain, which is a smart contract platform. Every transaction on the Ethereum blockchain, including swaps on Uniswap and Balancer, requires execution of a smart contract code which requires computational resources provided by the network's nodes. Therefore, each transaction has to pay gas fees, which compensate network nodes for the work they do in validating and processing the transaction.

In contrast, the Bitcoin Lightning Network is a layer-2 solution built on top of the Bitcoin blockchain. It allows users to transact "off-chain" by opening payment channels between two parties, and updating the state of these channels without requiring each transaction to be confirmed on the main blockchain. Instead, multiple transactions can be processed instantaneously as long as the payment channel remains open. The Lightning Network also relies on a network of nodes, but these nodes are not required to perform expensive computations and as a result, the fees for transacting on the Lightning Network are typically much lower than on-chain Bitcoin transactions.

It is technically possible to build similar layer-2 solutions on top of the Ethereum blockchain, and some projects like Loopring and zkSync are doing so. However, these solutions are still in their early stages and require significant development and adoption to become widely used and accessible to everyday users.

Comment: Thank you. Why is a bitcoin lightning transfer less resource heavy than a swap though? If ethereum had something similar to a lightning network, couldn't we settle swaps "off-chain" on a swap channel for a while before updating the main chain?